# Javascript - Capturing hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, hierarchy

Say I have the following set of code?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div><span>Text that I want to capture</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If the user clicks on the span element, I want to capture the text in the element, and then capture the hierarchy of the element. The goal is to come back and compare it against the captured text later.

Is there a library to help me accomplish this? If not, can you point me to some sample JS code that does this? I've been trying to figure it out the whole day, but can't seem to.

Comment: What do you mean by _capture the hierarchy of the element_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an array of all parent elements up to the root (`<html>`) from the clicked element using `$([clicked element]).parents()`. See [**JQuery documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Try playing with it via forking this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/qyhs6/)

Comment: This is really cool. I can then take the result, reverse it and save it in the db.

Would I then be able to traverse the dom with something like this:
$(array_db[0] > array_db[1]) where array_db is the list of parents I captured?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `$(array_db[0] > array_db[1])`. You can use `$.each` to traverse the array and act on all or certain elements from it.

Comment: Assume the reverse of parents is the following - ["HTML", "BODY", "DIV", "DIV", "DIV"], and I save this to a array variable (array_db). can I traverse the dom like this - $(array_db[0] > array_db[1]...)?

Comment: Hi @darudude, see modified answer

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need library for that. You can store clicked elements in some array and then just get their `parentNode`'s - to have an hierarchy:

```
element.parentNode.tagName
```

#### Example

```
document.write('<body><div><div><div><span>Text that I want to capture</span></div></div></div></body>');
document.querySelector('span').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var hierarchy = [];
    var parent = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
    while (parent) {
        parent.tagName && hierarchy.push(parent.tagName);
        parent = parent.parentNode
    }
    console.log(hierarchy.reverse()); // ["HTML", "BODY", "DIV", "DIV", "DIV"]
});
```